# Upgraded from spring 3.X mvc to 5.X mvc

Tags: spring-security

I am using WebApplicationInitializer for start up . When I include spring security chain filter , the login page request returns 200 empty response . When i remove the same , the login page opens perfectly. Can you help ?

My Web intializer class

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {


        XmlWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.setConfigLocations("/WEB-INF/****/applicationContext.xml","/WEB-INF/*****/spring-security-db.xml","/WEB-INF/***/dispatcher-servlet.xml","/WEB-INF/***/doc-views.xml");
        dispatcherContext.setServletContext(container);
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(dispatcherContext));
        container.addListener(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
        container.addListener(new DriverRegistrationListener());


         DelegatingFilterProxy delegatingFilterProxy =
              container.createFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.class);

     delegatingFilterProxy.setServletContext(container);
     delegatingFilterProxy.setContextAttribute("org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcher");

              container.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain",  delegatingFilterProxy).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*"); 
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));

        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

        initalizeLog4j(container);
    }

    private void initalizeLog4j(ServletContext container) {

        EnumSet<DispatcherType> dispEnumSet = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.ERROR,
                DispatcherType.INCLUDE, DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD);

        container.addFilter("log4j2ServletFilter", new Log4jServletFilter()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispEnumSet, true,
                "/*");
        container.addListener(new Log4jServletContextListener());

        LoggerContext context = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
        File log4j2File = new File(container.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/******/****/log4j2.xml"));

        // this will force a reconfiguration
        context.setConfigLocation(log4j2File.toURI());

    }

}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee                                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->

<!--  added all filters and listeners to atrix.common.controller.MyWebAppInitializer -->
    <jsp-config>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>http://asymmetrix/custom/csrf</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/***/csrf.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
    </jsp-config>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
        <!-- <cookie-config>        
                  <http-only>true</http-only>        
                  <secure>true</secure>    
          </cookie-config>  -->
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/***/***/login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

   <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>  
    <location>/WEB-INF/***/***/404.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>  
    <location>/WEB-INF/***/***/500.jsp</location>
  </error-page>

</web-app>
```

I have added all my filters in webappintializer . I am upgrading from spring 3.X to 5.X. Previously these filters where available in web.xml

I have investigated and found that below line is the problem

```
     <security:custom-filter  after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="securityFilters" />  


<beans:bean id="securityFilters"
    class="org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter">
    <beans:property name="filters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="sqlInjectionCheckFilter" />
            <beans:ref bean="hostCheckFilter" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Give an example of the code you're having trouble with. Add it by editing the content of your question.

Comment: can you help me now ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Java or Spring. My comment was part of community moderation. Wait a bit for a response from another user who knows this thing.